# Silverlight + PHP - AES crypt

Tags: php, silverlight, cryptography, aes

Problem with cryptography protocol between Silverlight and PHP.

I tried to encrypt text value in Silverlight and decrypt it in PHP with help of AES algorithm.
This example how I encrypt it in Silverlight:

```
<!-- language: lang-cs -->
SaveFileDialog dlg = new SaveFileDialog();
dlg.Filter = "Crypt file  (CRP)|*.crp";

bool res = dlg.ShowDialog().Value;

if (res == true)
{
    Stream outStream = dlg.OpenFile();

    AesManaged cryptAlg = new AesManaged();
    ICryptoTransform encryptor = cryptAlg.CreateEncryptor(_encryptKey, _encryptIv);
    CryptoStream cryptStream = new CryptoStream(outStream, encryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Write);

    byte[] buffer = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(textBox1.Text);
    int size = buffer.Length;
    cryptStream.Write(buffer, 0, size);
    cryptStream.Close();
    outStream.Close();
}
```

This example how I decrypt it in PHP:

```
<!-- language: lang-php -->
function fb_get_contents($filename) {
    $fp = fopen($filename, "rb");
    $cc = fgets($fp);
    fclose($fp);
    return $cc;
}

$value = fb_get_contents($_FILES['file']['tmp_name']);

$module = mcrypt_module_open(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128, '', MCRYPT_MODE_CBC, ''); 
$blockSize = mcrypt_get_block_size(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128, MCRYPT_MODE_CBC);

$key = substr($key, 0, 16);
$iv = $key;
$rc = mcrypt_generic_init($module, $key, $iv); 

$value = base64_decode($value);
$value = mdecrypt_generic($module, $value); 

//apply pkcs7 padding removal
$packing = ord($value[strlen($value) - 1]);
if($packing && $packing < $blockSize){
    for($P = strlen($value) - 1; $P >= strlen($value) - $packing; $P--){
        if(ord($value{$P}) != $packing){
            $packing = 0;
        }//end if
    }//end for
}//end if 

$value = substr($value, 0, strlen($value) - $packing);
```

And it doesn't work. I think this is could be a problem with padding parameter of AES algorithm. Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean by "it doesn't work"?

Comment: It means that text value after decrypt isn't equals to input text value.

Comment: Please show more complete example, with your IV and keys.

Try to set them to some nonsense like [0,0,0,0..]. I suspect you have problems with byte representations of them.

Answer (score 0):

Absent the rest of the c# code and what you mean by "its not working", I can't be sure, but I'd say this is your problem.

$iv = $key;

You want to pull the iv form cryptAlg.IV

Moreover, I don't think the default encoding is PKCS7 for AesManaged and 2) you sometimes need to call flush on the buffer to get the last block written.